# Python работа с неописанными аргументами командной строки

Tags: python

Можно ли как то работать с параметрами командной строки при помощи библиотеки optparse или argparse, которые не описаны в add_option? Что бы те которые описаны разбирались, а те которые нет просто передавались как строка или лист параметров.
Такое возможно?

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option ("-c", "--config", dest="config")
```

и запустить файл с параметрами

```
start.py -c test -i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы распознать известные (описанные с помощью `ArgumentParser.add_argument()` метода) аргументы командной строки, а остальное вернуть как список, можно [использовать `ArgumentParser.parse_known_args()` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing):

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar')
>>> parser.parse_known_args(['--foo', '--badger', 'BAR', 'spam'])
(Namespace(bar='BAR', foo=True), ['--badger', 'spam'])
```

Видно, что известные и неизвестные опции могут быть вперемежку заданы.

Answer (score 1):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-f', '--Func')  # которые описаны
p.add_argument('items', nargs='*')  # которые не описаны

print(p.parse_args().__dict__.items())
>>> dict_items([('Func', None), ('items', [])])
```